# Returning a result with incremented rows in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ranking

How do I return a row and an ascending counter as a result set?

Comment: Once you have the RDBMS that you're using, do a search and find one of the 20 versions of this question that have already been answered here...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your RDMS, but there's probably a `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Comment: Or RANK or DENSE_RANK if you want the records to be numbered in specific order.

Comment: Yes I want to rank my result rows.

Answer (score 2):

If its SQL Server you can do it with the following syntax:

```
SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) AS Id, column1, column2, ....
```

Comment: @Philip: such crucial information **ought to be** part of your original question! That's what those tags are for! "SQL" just means: Structured Query Language - that doesn't help at all...